Is there a closed form for $\sin(x +\cos(x + \sin(x + \cos(x + \cdots))))$?
Is there a closed form expression to represent the function obtained by taking nested repeating sums of alternating sin and cos functions?
Something looking like this:
$$\sin(x +\cos(x + \sin(x + \cos(x + \cdots))))$$
I guess it could be defined this way:
$$L(x)=\sin(x+\cos(x+L(x)))$$
I have plotted several iterations of the function here:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h2aj27gveg
Although you can't algebraically solve for it using that definition, maybe there's some other clever way to get to a closed form expression I'm overlooking.
If there's not a closed form solution, is there a name for the numerical approximation of this function? It looks like it converges based on the graphs.

I think it would be a could idea to have a plot in the question body as opposed to behind a link. The behavior is a bit curious to tell you the truth :-)

Based on twenty iterations:
$$L(x)\approx0.341+0.767 \sin x-0.078\cos x+0.010\sin 2x+0.393\cos2x-0.066\sin 3x+0.133\cos3x+\cdots.$$ Not enough terms here for any insights as the Fourier series may converge more slowly :-(

You can solve for $x$ by noticing $y+(2k+1)\pi-\sin^{-1}(y)=x+y+\cos(x+y), y+2k\pi+\sin^{-1}(y)=x+y+\cos(x+y),k\in\Bbb Z,y=L(x)$. Now $x+y$ is in a Kepler equation with methods to solve it here. If $L(x)=x-w$, then $x=\sin(\cos(w)+x)+w$ which is harder to solve for $w$

"nested repeating sums of alternating sin and cos functions" does not describe your formula.  Because of that $x+{}$ in there.

You can use recursive definitions in Desmos. So you don't have to write a separate definition for each iteration see here your example using recursion. This saves you a lot of time.

There is almost likely no closed form. However, to find the Fourier series for $y=L(x)$ in $y=\sin(x+\cos(x+y))$, substitute $y=\frac\pi2-w-x$, set $x=a$, and subtract $\sin(a)$ so the curve passes through $(\pm\pi,\pm\pi)$:
$$f(w)=\sin(\sin(w)+a)+w-\sin(a)=\frac\pi2-x-\sin(a)$$
Setting up the Fourier series for $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, substituting $g(t)\to t$, and integrating by parts gives:
$$g(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}a_n e^{i nx},a_n=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t)e^{-i nt}dt=\frac in\cos(\pi n)-\frac in\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inf(t)}dt$$
One extracts $a_0=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi t df(t)=\lim\limits_{n\to0}a_n $ becoming $\sin(a)-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(\sin(t)+a)dt=\sin(a)(1-J_0(1))$, evaluates $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\frac ine^{inx}\cos(\pi n)=x$, and takes the real part. Thereafter, a Jacobi Anger expansion is applied with the Bessel function of the first kind $J_n(x)$:
$$g(x)=\sin(a)(1-J_0(1))+x-\operatorname{Re}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\frac{iJ_k(-n)}{2\pi n}e^{in(\sin(a)+x)} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(k(\sin(t)+a)-n t)}dt$$
The inner integral gives $J_n(x)$:
$$\boxed{f(x)=\sin(\sin(x)+a)+x-\sin(a)\implies f^{-1}(x)=\sin(a)(1-J_0(1))+x+\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}\frac{(-1)^k}nJ_k(n)J_n(k)\sin(nx+n\sin(a)+ak)}$$
Since $L(x)=\frac\pi2-x-g\left(\frac\pi2-x-\sin(a)\right)$, the Fourier series is therefore:
$$\bbox[2px, border: 3px blue groove]{y=\sin(x+\cos(x+y))\implies y=L(x)=\sin(x)J_0(1)-\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}\frac{(-1)^k}nJ_k(n)J_n(k)\sin\left(x(k-n)+\frac{\pi n}2\right)}$$
shown here by plotting $y=L(x)$ and the truncated series:

